# Google Drive REST API: Querying on activity

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to get all files, in a parent, that have been added to this parent after a date?

Obvously without looping on all files.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the available filter in the API's including those which can be put in the ["q" parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/query-parameters). What you wanted is not possible as of now. But there is an orderBy parameter which you can use to make it easier to pick files created after a certain date.

Comment: Yes i saw that but it's not on the creation date that i need to query. But if you say that it's not possible, i will find another way to do what i need. However thank you.

Comment: @damien yeah its not possible as of now